# Gradle build - Could not determine the dependencies of task ':myLibrary:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-library, gradle-experimental

I have just migrated my project to gradle-experimental:0.4.0 to use JNI. I have followed the instructions [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental/0-4-0)

The project consists of a library and an application. I cannot get round this error (tried the usual clean and invalidate cache/restart):

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':myLibrary:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'
```

The library build fine but this error appears when I build the app module. Here are my modified build.gradle scripts:

Project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Library (build OK):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.library'

model
{
    android {
        buildToolsVersion="23.0.1"


        defaultConfig.with {
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel=16
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel=16

            testInstrumentationRunner="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        }

    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled=true
            proguardFiles.add(file('proguard.cfg'))
        }
    }
}
```

App (this build fails):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.1.1.jar')
    compile project(':myLibrary')
}


model
{
    android
    {
        compileSdkVersion='Google Inc.:Google APIs:16'
        buildToolsVersion="23.0.1"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId="my.app.ID"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel=16
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel=16
        }

    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled=true
            proguardFiles.add(file('proguard.cfg'))
        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone seen this error when moving to gradle-experimental?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so removing the proguard line from the library build file fixed this:

```
--proguardFiles.add(file('proguard.cfg'))
```